# How to read multiple json files from s3 and implement pagination

Tags: json, amazon-s3, pagination

I have few json files of same format at an location in s3. I want to read all the json files from that location and merge them and check if the size of merged json is greater than 10MB then implement pagination and send at max 10mb json data back as rest response. Can any one suggest how to do it

Comment: Please come up with an approach using java

Comment: Do you have a specific question about an implementation?

Comment: Anon just want to know how to read json files in an paginated manner from an s3 location